# Android change Tab image (not background)

Tags: android

I am using a TabHost which has 3 tabs. Each tab has a image + text.

```
spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("MyTasks")
           .setIndicator(Html.fromHtml("<b><H2>My Tasks</H2></b>"),  getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.task ))
               .setContent(intent);    
   tabHost.addTab(spec);
```

I want to change image when I select a tab. I used following code to change it ...

```
 TabWidget tw = getTabWidget(); 
   View leftTabView = tw.getChildAt(0); 
   leftTabView.setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.tab1_drawable));
```

tab1_drawable is  a xml (selector and items for each state). THIS IS SETTING AND CHANGING BACKGROUND NOT THE IMAGE I SET. How can I change it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of changing the drawable through code, why not use a [state-list drawable](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html#StateList)? Then you'd just specify a different drawable for the tab when it is selected.

Example, ic_tab_tasks.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/ic_tab_tasks_selected"
          android:state_selected="true" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/ic_tab_tasks_normal" />
</selector>
```

Then, when you're setting the tab indicator's drawable initially, just use the state-list drawable.

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
  private int index_tab = 0;  
  private TabWidget tabWidget;  
    @Override  
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {  
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);  
        setContentView(R.layout.index_layout);    
        TabHost t = (TabHost)findViewById(R.id.testhost);   
        t.setOnTabChangedListener(new OnTabChangeListener() {  
            @Override  
            public void onTabChanged(String tabId) {  
                tabChanged(tabId);  
            }  
        });  
    } 
 public void tabChanged(String tabId) {  
  if (index_tab != (Integer.valueOf(tabId) - 1)) {  
    tabWidget.getChildAt(Integer.valueOf(tabId) - 1)  
      .setBackgroundDrawable(  
       getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.tab1_drawable));  
       tabWidget.getChildAt(index_tab).setBackgroundDrawable(null);  
        index_tab = Integer.valueOf(tabId) - 1;  
    }  
}
```